# Singularity of Morphism and Its Extension

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I really need help with this question.

> Assume you have a morphism $\varphi: \mathbb{A}^2 \rightarrow
> > \mathbb{A}^1$ such that $\varphi (x,y)= x^2-y^4$.
>
> 1) Find all points in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\varphi^{-1}(a)$ is
>   singular. And its type of singularity.
>
> 2) If $Y_{a}$ is the closure of curve $\varphi^{-1}(a)$ in
>   $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ and L is line at $\infty$ (z=0), find the point
>   $Y_{a}\cap L$.
>
> 3) Let $\psi: \mathbb{P}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{1}$ be rational
>   map that extends $\varphi$, find the domain of $\psi$ and the fiber
>   $\psi^{-1}(\infty)$.

This is a reducible curve that I've never seen before. I do not know what can I do!

I found $(0,0)$ is a singular point by using Jacobian. For the second one, I took homogenization of curve but I couldn't how to find the intersection with the line at infinity. For the last one, I have no idea.

Comment: Hi, welcome on MSE ! You will have more chance to get answer if you explain what are your thought, what did you try, ...

Comment: I found (0,0) is a singular point by using Jacobian. For the second one, I took homogenization of curve but I couldn't how to find the intersection with the line at infinity. For the last one, I have no idea. :( I am really upset because of this question.

Comment: I'm writing an answer, next time don't hesitate to include what you did in the question itself by the way.

Comment: I really appreciate. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As you said, by the Jacobian criterion indeed $\varphi^{-1}(0)$ is the unique singular fiber  and the singularity type is two tangent parabolas $(x-y^2)(x+y^2) = 0$.

2) The fiber has homogenous equation $x^2z^2 = y^4 + az^4 $. Its intersection with the line at infinity given by $z=0$ and the previous equation, i.e this is the point $(1,0,0)$ (with multiplicity $4$).

3)  We take $$\psi(x,y,z) = \frac{x^2z^2 - y^4}{z^4}$$

and the domain of $\psi$ is exactly when $z^4 \neq 0$ or $x^2z^2 - y^4 \neq 0$. This means that the domain is  $\Bbb P^2 \backslash \{(1,0,0)\}$. This is not surprising since by the previous question, $(1,0,0)$ was in the closure of each fibers !

Finally, the fiber over $\infty$ is simply given by the line $z=0$, minus the point $[1:0:0]$. For completness, the other projective fibers over $[a:1] \in \Bbb P^1 $  are given by $\{ (x,y,1) : x^2 = y^4 + a \}$. Notice that it does not include the point $(1,0,0)$ by what we said, even though this point is in the closure of all the fibers.

A final remark : this is possible to find a surface $X$ and a morphism $f : X \to \Bbb P^2$ so that $\psi$ becomes defined everywhere, this morphism is called a blow-up and making your map defined everywhere is typically why algebraic geometers introduce blow-up.

Answer (score 0):

About your final remark, If I make blow-up, can I get a such a morphism $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{1}$ which an extension of $\varphi$ ? Does it have to be $\mathbb{P}^{2}$

Comment: Hi, don't hesitate to open a new question or to leave a comment under my answer, the "answer box" is not the best place for such a question :-)
To answer your question : the blow-up is a map $f : X \to \Bbb P^2$ and it will have the property that there is a well defined map $\tilde{\psi} : X \to \Bbb P^2$ so that $f \circ \psi$ coincide with $\tilde{\psi}$. $X$ won't be $\Bbb P^2$ but a slightly more complicated space.

Comment: By the way, do you have any suggestion to learn these stuff that related to my first and second questions, any book or lecture notes etc. ? 
I am not comfortable to play these algebraic geometry toys. :(( But I want to learn more.

Comment: Try to read Fulton's _Algebraic curves_. If you are stuck you can come back to ask some questions on this website. Good luck !